# Executing a command stored in a variable from PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a command that I have build and stored in a variable in PowerShell. This command works if I do a [Write-Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Host?view=powershell-5.1https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Host) and copy and paste into a standard `cmd.exe` window.

How do I execute this command from inside my script?

I have tried several combination of Invoke-Command or Invoke-Expression with no luck.

This is how I built the variable:

```
$cmd1 = $arcprg + $arcdir + "\" + $site1 + "-" + $hst + "-" + $yesterday + ".zip " + $logpath1 + "u_ex" + $yesterday + ".log"
```

This is what the variable looks like if it is printed to the screen:

```
7z.exe a -tzip c:\arc_logs\site-host-at-web1-100827.zip c:\inetpub\logs\logfiles\w3svc1\u_ex100827.log
```

Comment: isn't this just the '&' symbol?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074507/what-does-the-symbol-in-powershell-mean/22074638

Comment: Perfectly valid to build up a command to run an external program such as 7z.   But however one does this in a general case, one will want to be sure not to blindly use parameters that come from potentially untrusted sources that could cause a malicious action to be performed.

Answer (score 266, accepted):

Here is yet another way without `Invoke-Expression` but with two variables
(command:string and parameters:array). It works fine for me. Assume
`7z.exe` is in the system path.

```sh
$cmd = '7z.exe'
$prm = 'a', '-tzip', 'c:\temp\with space\test1.zip', 'C:\TEMP\with space\changelog'

& $cmd $prm
```

If the command is known (7z.exe) and only parameters are variable then this will do

```sh
$prm = 'a', '-tzip', 'c:\temp\with space\test1.zip', 'C:\TEMP\with space\changelog'

& 7z.exe $prm
```

BTW, `Invoke-Expression` with one parameter works for me, too, e.g. this works

```sh
$cmd = '& 7z.exe a -tzip "c:\temp\with space\test2.zip" "C:\TEMP\with space\changelog"'

Invoke-Expression $cmd
```

P.S. I usually prefer the way with a parameter array because it is easier to
compose programmatically than to build an expression for `Invoke-Expression`.

Comment: That is great. It is starting to come together now. Instead of 'c:\temp\with space\test1.zip' can i just use a $variable ?

Do i need to place it is "" or '' ?

Comment: Splatting seems to work the same: & $cmd @prm  But I'm curious about why is that

Comment: This doesn't work: `$path=C:\blah` and `& $path\test.exe blah1`.

Comment: @Exegesis Do it this way: `& "$path\test.exe" blah1`

Comment: @RomanKuzmin It works! `$path="C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv"; & "$path\appcmd"`

Comment: `invoke-expression` needs one string whereas `&` can have several `strings`.

Comment: coming from bash `&` feels more wrong

Comment: Thanks, Roman! The magical ampersand did the trick perfectly ^_^

Comment: I'm trying to use this with the `Get-AzRoleAssignment` command, but getting this error: `A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'`. Are some special tricks required for this case?

Comment: It's difficult to tell without seeing the full code and knowing the syntax of this command.

Answer (score 66):

Try invoking your command with `Invoke-Expression`:

```
Invoke-Expression $cmd1
```

Here is a working example on my machine:

```
$cmd = "& 'C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe' a -tzip c:\temp\test.zip c:\temp\test.txt"
Invoke-Expression $cmd
```

---

`iex` is an *alias* for `Invoke-Expression` so you could do:

```bsh
iex $cmd1
```

For a full list :
Visit https://ss64.com/ps/ for more `Powershell` stuff.

Good Luck...

Comment: Tells me 
The term '7z.exe a -tzip c:\arc_logs\site-host-at-web1-100827.zip c:\inetpub\logs\logfiles\w3svc1\u_ex100827.log' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At :line:14 char:1
+ & <<<<  $cmd1

Comment: @Travis: Oops. the ampersand is works if there are no args. I updated the post with a solution for your command.

Comment: I have tried invoke-expression before and it has not worked. 
It spits out the error:

Bad numeric constant: 7.
At :line:1 char:2
+ 7z <<<< .exe a -tzip c:\arc_logs\site-host-at-web1-100827.zip c:\inetpub\logs\logfiles\w3svc1\u_ex100827.log

It almost seems like it is trying to evaluate it instead of executing it.

Comment: @Travis: It may be that 7z.exe is not on your path. Verify that it is on the path and/or try giving the full path name to the executable in your expression.

Comment: @Travis: I just confirmed on my own system that 7z.exe gave the error you described, just typing from the command prompt, but with the full path to 7z.exe (for me, it was `'C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe'`, I could execute 7z.exe.

Comment: Yes i test that out and added 7z.exe to the path. Still have the problem.

Comment: @Travis: Sorry. It takes cobbling together all the elements of our conversation. I've updated my post with a working example. You will need to change out the paths, but the structure should still apply.