# What does the & symbol in powershell mean?

Tags: powershell

```
$tool = 'C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.07\bin\gswin64c.exe'

& $tool -q -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=tiffg4 $param -r300 $pdf.FullName -c quit
```

Can someone explain to me how the this works? What exactly does the & symbol do/mean in powershell?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

`&` is the call operator which allows you to execute a command, a script, or a function.
For more details:
[SS64 documentation: Call operator (&)](http://ss64.com/ps/call.html)
[Microsoft Docs: Call operator &](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#call-operator-)

```
Syntax
      & "[path] command" [arguments]
```

Example:

```powershell
$LocalComputerName = & $ENV:windir\System32\HostName.exe
```

Also, if you use an IDE (such as `PowerGUI`) you can block it from opening a separate window when executing a secondary process:

```powershell
& more
Start-Process "my_script.here"
```

Comment: What is `& more` ?

Comment: @kjhf When using an IDE, if the new process you execute opens a new separate window to run in, you can hide that by using `& more`.

Comment: See also [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#call-operator-).

Comment: what is the difference between `&` and `Start-Process`?

Comment: @Ooker `&` runs a proces in the child scope; however `Start-Process` as well as just running the command runs it in the current scope. `&` is kinda like starting a deamon.

Comment: I can't tell you why, but when using the Call operator (&) in my Powershell scripts to run uninstall commands with parameters, I need to use single quotes & 'path\to\exe' /switch when specifying the path, not double quotes.