# PowerShell V6 command invocation does not work in script

Tags: powershell

I run this command script:

`$hm = "$Env:USERPROFILE"
$eclipse_path = "$hm\eclipse\committers-2019-09\eclipse\eclipse.exe"
$sp = {
"$eclipse_path -data C:\SharedData\Projects\Tutorial &"
Write-Host "Eclipse starting"
}
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $sp`

with the following results:

`>>> bin/dev.ps1                                                                                                        C:\Users\jgoss\eclipse\committers-2019-09\eclipse\eclipse.exe -data C:\SharedData\Projects\Tutorial &
Eclipse starting                                                                                                       >>>`

It appears that the main command was not executed but the echo command was executed. If I run the main command standalone in Windows Terminal as shown, the command works as desired:

```
>>> C:\Users\jgoss\eclipse\committers-2019-09\eclipse\eclipse.exe -data C:\SharedData\Projects\Tutorial &
```

I simply cut and paste the contents of the first command in the script block and it worked as I want. The program eclipse.exe was started in the background. Why does this not work within a script block?

Comment: The first command in your Scriptblock $sp is actually a write-output "...". Maybe you take a look at the start-process cmdlet or use the [ampersand &](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074507/what-does-the-symbol-in-powershell-mean) symbol.

Answer (score 1):

This would get it to work, but there are easier ways to do it.  I'm using notepad as an example anyone can reproduce.

```
$hm = "c:\windows\system32"
$eclipse_path = "$hm\notepad.exe"
$sp = {
  & $eclipse_path c:\users\js\foo\note.ps1
  Write-Host "Eclipse starting" } 
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $sp
```

For example in your $profile you can add the eclipse folder to your path:

```
$eclipse_path = "$home\eclipse\committers-2019-09\eclipse"
$env:path += $eclipse_path
```

Then you could simply run eclipse and whatever filename.  You could use control-r to search the command history for the last time you ran it.