# How to use mstest in github actions?

Tags: mstest, github-actions

tried specifying the location in the github actions for mstest
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe".

But it says cannot find path as it does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is you pipeline using the [`Setup Msbuild`](https://github.com/microsoft/setup-msbuild) task?

Here is an example of pipeline to display `MsTest`'s help:

```yaml
name: Display MsTest helper

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '**' 

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - name: setup-msbuild
        uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1

      - name: Run a one-line script
        run:  '& "$(vswhere -property installationPath)\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /help'
```

Comment: It's to invoke a command after resolving a variable name. You can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074507/what-does-the-symbol-in-powershell-mean