# Run Python File in Terminal - in VSCode - preceding the command with an ampersand "&" - what is it?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm attempting to code and run a python program in VSCode.
I have Python 3.8.1 with vitrual env.
When I click the green "play" button to "Run Python File in Terminal", the command invoked in the terminal starts with an "&" symbol, like this:

```
(virtual) ...tg-test> & "c:\Users\...\python.exe" "c:\Users\...\MyProgram.py"
```

[image]

When I try to remove the & it already flags a problem by turning the prompt sign ">" to red.

What is this symbol for and how can I run my code in the terminal by just calling **python.exe myfile.py**?

Thanks!

Comment: Python is a program. When you run a python file you're calling python to run the script you've written. If you look at your environment variables you should see this path in the Path variable, this is how your machine knows where the python.exe file is so when your type "python some_script.py" it runs python.exe

Comment: @DvirH Thanks. I am asking about the "&" sign BEFORE the call to the python program...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074507.

Comment: THanks @Luke! just what I was looking for...

Comment: Luke pointed me to the answer here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074507/what-does-the-symbol-in-powershell-mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074507/what-does-the-symbol-in-powershell-mean)