# How to Convert a C# program to AZ Pipeline extension

Tags: c#, azure-pipelines

I wrote a C# program that runs inside an Azure build pipeline. Whenever the pipeline executes, the executing pipeline builds the solution and then runs a batch script that executes the newly compiled exe.
How could I convert this application to a private AZ pipeline marketplace step?
I am unable to find an example or instructions on how to do this.

I have searched various sites and I can only find examples of code in React, JScript, etc. The C# code already exists and uses various NuGet packages and SDKs.

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074507/what-does-the-symbol-in-powershell-mean

Comment: Can you provide some more information so that community will help you to solve your issue.

Comment: I would like to create a task that i can publish in the Az Devops marketplace that can be used in a Build Pipeline. I would like some links to explanations or samples of how to do this in C##