# How to execute a ruby command stored in a variable in powershell

Tags: ruby, powershell

I am executing a command of the form `rake drive:unit_tests:load_data  parameters here'. I get the error`is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

I used the code in my `ps1` file :

```
$dat1 = one ruby command | Out-String
# $dat1  will contain the value - rake drive:unit_tests:load_data
$dat2 = "  parameters here"
$dat3 = $dat1 + $dat2
& $dat3
```

Source: [Executing a Command stored in a Variable from Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592851/executing-a-command-stored-in-a-variable-from-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like powershell doesn't understand the command `rake`, which may mean that it's not in your `PATH`.

Run:

```
Get-Command -CommandType Application | Where-Object { $_.Name -ilike 'rake.*' }
```

If this comes back blank, then powershell doesn't know where to find rake. You can use a fully qualified path name to invoke it, or you can add the location of rake to your `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution. The main blog which helped me is [here](http://powertoe.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/dynamic-code-in-powershell/). The concept it "dynamic code" in powershell.

What did not work:

```
$dat3 = {$dat1 + $dat2}
& $dat3
```

This only prints the value of $dat3, but does not actually execute it. I go a little further down the article and try the code at the bottom. Success !!!

What works:

```
$dat3 = $dat1 + $dat2
$dat3 = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.NewScriptBlock($dat3)
& $dat3
```

Related powershell concepts: Command line parsing mode, Expression parsing mode 
Read them here - http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2007/11/24/effective-powershell-item-10-understanding-powershell-parsing-modes/