# Powershell - Using 7zip with Parameters

Tags: powershell, 7zip

I'm using Powershell(V4) and I'm following the code give [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592851/executing-a-command-stored-in-a-variable-from-powershell),however, it gives me an error when I run the code.

**My Code:**

```
[string]$zipPath="C:\Users\someUser\7z.exe"
[string]$parameters= 'a', '-tzip','C:\Users\someUser\Desktop\Archive.zip','C:\Users\someUser\Desktop\Test'
```

**Powershell View:**

PS C:\Users\someUser> $zipPath="C:\Users\someUser\7z.exe"
    $parameters= 'a', '-tzip','C:\Users\someUser\Desktop\Archive.zip','C:\Users\someUser\Desktop\Test'
    & $zipPath $parameters

```
& $zipPath $parameters
```

**Output:**

```
7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18


 Error:
 Incorrect command line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Start-Process` with `$parameters` as the `-ArgumentList`:

```
Start-Process $zipPath -ArgumentList $parameters -wait
```

Comment: Yes, that worked as well. Thanks. Just out of curiosity, why didn't work the way the example showed?

Comment: It should've worked if you'd just had it as a normal string, but I guess `&` doesn't know how to parse an array to get program arguments, whereas `Start-Process` does.

Answer (score 0):

That passes all of your arguments as a single string e.g.:

```
2> $ec = 'echoargs'
3> & $ec $parameters
Arg 0 is <a -tzip C:\Users\someUser\Desktop\Archive.zip C:\Users\someUser\Desktop\Test>

Command line:
"C:\Users\hillr\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pscx\Apps\EchoArgs.exe"  "a -tzip C:\Users\someUser\Desktop\Archive.
zip C:\Users\someUser\Desktop\Test"
```

Just pass your arguments normally:

```
4> & $ec a -tzip C:\Users\someUser\Desktop\Archive.zip C:\Users\someUser\Desktop\Test
Arg 0 is <a>
Arg 1 is <-tzip>
Arg 2 is <C:\Users\someUser\Desktop\Archive.zip>
Arg 3 is <C:\Users\someUser\Desktop\Test>

Command line:
"C:\Users\hillr\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pscx\Apps\EchoArgs.exe"  a -tzip C:\Users\someUser\Desktop\Archive.z
ip C:\Users\someUser\Desktop\Test
```

BTW echoargs is a tool from the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com).