# How can I run NuGet commands in a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, nuget

I am trying to run some NuGet commands through a PowerShell script, but PowerShell prompts errors like: "Unknown command:'-set'" or "Unexpected token '-set' in expression or statement"

I'm trying to run the following NuGet commands:

```
$nugetExe = "C:\TestAutomation\NuGet\nuget.exe"

Invoke-Expression "$nugetExe config -set http_proxy.user= txxxxxx"
Invoke-Expression "$nugetExe config -set http_proxy.password= njhbjhb"
```

**PS.**: The PowerShell version is 5.1 and NuGet is 4.6.**This code works fine through Windows CMD.

On the CMD command line I run it like this, and it works:

```
nuget.exe config -set http_proxy.user=txxxxxx
nuget.exe config -set http_proxy.password= njhbjhb
```

Comment: But even when I coment the third command It does not work. I will remove it from there, so it is more clear.

Comment: If you have working batch code, post that in your question.

Comment: Sorry I am not running it through batch file, but I added there how I am running it directly through CMD

Comment: I get "Unknown command: '-set'" running `nuget.exe -set http_proxy.user= t123654` with `cmd.exe` and NuGet 4.7.1.5393 (latest stable) and NuGet 4.6.2.5055.

Comment: How strange, for me it runs smothly through cmd. I just run it now to assure and everything is ok, my Nuget.config is updated. Are you running from the nuget.exe directory?

Comment: Sorry I saw what is wrong, try this:                                                          nuget.exe config -set http_proxy.user=t123645.                                                I will update the question too. But the error still occurs in powershell.

Answer (score 2):

nuget.exe doesn't have a `set` parameter.

*[NuGet CLI reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference)*

I think you are missing the `config` parameter if you are trying to set the proxy:

```
nuget.exe config -set http_proxy=http://my.proxy.address:port
```

*[config command (NuGet CLI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-config)*

*[NuGet behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232160/nuget-behind-proxy)*

To run with PowerShell:

```
$nugetExe = "D:\Scrap\New folder\NuGet.exe"

$Params = @(

    "config",
    "-Set", "HTTP_PROXY.USER=domain\user"
    "-configfile" "D:\scrap\New folder\my.config"
)

& $nugetExe $Params
```

Comment: Actually I alredy have this working, but with cmd command line. What I need now is to run this code in a powershell script.

Comment: and you should be able to do it with Invoke-Expression if you prefer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3593445/1426007

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It is just about the way of writing it. It should be like this:

```
.\nuget config -Set http_proxy.user=txxxxxx

.\nuget config -Set http_proxy.password=njhbjhb
```