# How do I do the bash equivalent of $PROGPATH/program in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, syntax, command-line-arguments

In GNU/Linux I would do:

```
PROGPATH=/long/and/complicated/path/to/some/bin
$PROGPATH/program args...
```

but in Powershell if I try this:

```
$PROGPATH=\long\and\complicated\path\to\some\bin
$PROGPATH\program args...
```

I get:

```
At script.ps1:2 char:...
+ $PROGPATH\program args ...
+          ~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '\program' in expression or statement.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

So how do I do this simple thing I know how to do in bash, in Powershell?

Comment: take a look at the `call operator`, and at `Start-Process`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[js2010's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57677699/45375) shows the correct solution:

**Because your command name/path contains a *variable reference* (`$PROGPATH/...`), you must invoke it with `&`**: `& $PROGPATH\program args...`
The same applies if a [grouping expression, `(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--) is used, or a [subexpression, `$(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) is involved.

Additionally, **the same applies if a command name/path is *quoted* (`'...'` or `"..."`)**<sup>[1]</sup>, as is required if the path contains *spaces*, for instance.

To put it differently: **Direct invocation is only supported if the command name/path is a *verbatim, unquoted string***<sup>[1]</sup>; in all other cases, `&` must be used.

As for **why**:

**[`&`, the *call operator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#call-operator-) is necessary to force interpretation of a statement as a *command***, i.e. to have it parsed in *argument mode* (see below), **so as to result in *command execution* rather than *expression evaluation***.

**PowerShell has two fundamental [parsing modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing)**:

- ***argument mode***, which **works like a *traditional shell***, where the first token is a ***command name/path***, such as a cmdlet or an external program, with subsequent tokens representing the arguments, which only require quoting if they contain shell *metacharacters* (chars. with special meaning to PowerShell, such as spaces to separate tokens).
- ***expression mode***, which **works like expressions in *programming languages***.

PowerShell decides based on a statement's *first token* what parsing mode to apply:

**If, among other things, the first token starts with a *variable reference* or is a *quoted string*, PowerShell parses in *expression mode***.

- In expression mode, `\` *starts a new token*, and unrecognized token `\program` results in the syntax error you saw.
- (If you had used `/`, it would have been interpreted as the *division operator*, and `program` wouldn't be a valid divisor operand.)

---

<sup>[1] Note that if your executable path is a *literal* string (doesn't contain variable references of expressions) you may alternatively `` ` ``-escape *individual characters* (spaces) in lieu of enclosing entire string in `'...'` or `"..."`, in which case `&` is then not necessary; e.g.:

`` C:\Program` Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe ``

With a literal string you can even employ *partial* single- or double-quoting as long as the *first* token is *unquoted*; e.g.:

`C:\"Program Files"\Notepad++\notepad++.exe`</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Use the call operator "&".  https://ss64.com/ps/call.html

Related:  [Executing a command stored in a variable from PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592851/executing-a-command-stored-in-a-variable-from-powershell)

```powershell
$progpath = 'c:\windows\system32'
& $progpath\notepad somefile.txt
```

Something with a space:

```powershell
 & 'C:\Program Files\internet explorer\iexplore' yahoo.com
```

Other options, adding to the path:

```powershell
$env:path += ';C:\Program Files\internet explorer'
iexplore yahoo.com
```

And backquoting the spaces:

```powershell
C:\Program` Files\internet` explorer\iexplore yahoo.com
```