# Double dash in powershell seems to cause 'Unexpected token' error

Tags: powershell

I am running a command (part of [Chromium DevTools](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WNF-KqRSzPLUUfZqQG5AFeU_Ll8TfWYcJasa_XGf7ro/edit#)) which requires a double dash. Powershell (pwsh 7) seems to have trouble parsing the double dash:

```bsh
$ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --custom-devtools-frontend=file://C:\Users\mikem\Code\devtools\devtools-frontend\out\Default\resources\inspector
ParserError:
Line |
   1 | "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --custom-devtools-frontend=file://C:\Users\mikem\Code\devtools\devtools-frontend\out\Default\resources\inspector
     |                                                                  ^ Unexpected token
     | 'custom-devtools-frontend=file://C:\Users\mikem\Code\devtools\devtools-frontend\out\Default\resources\inspector'
     | in expression or statement.
```

How can I run the command, more specifically, how can I make pwsh handle double dashes?

Comment: Use `& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --custom-devtools-frontend=...` (Notice the `&` call operator in front)

Comment: This is a common question.  You can also add that folder to the path, or backquote the spaces and not quote the whole thing.

Comment: The [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57678081/45375) explains why `&`, the call operator, is needed in this situation.