# How to get around using apostrophe in double quotes with Powershell

Tags: powershell, escaping, invoke, backticks

I am working with Powershell.  My issue is that my file path (which does not exist on a local computer) has an apostrophe in it. Powershell is seeing this as a single quote, so it is giving me the following error: **The string is missing the terminator: '.** I thought that I could escape the single quote using a backtick, but that gave me the same error.

The error does not occur when I am doing the first line of code, and I don't even need the backtick for that part. I can even see that the contents of the variable matches up with the file path that I am using. It is only when I am doing the invoke-expression part that it is giving me the error.

I am using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-7, so I don't think the second line of the code is the problem.

My code is listed below:

```
$code = "\\example\example\John_Doe`'s_Folder\example.ps1"
invoke-expression -command $code
```

I have also tried wrapping the entire file path in double-quotes and single-quotes, but my program did not like that either.  I can't remove the apostrophe as we have over a hundred of systems that are directing to John_Doe's_Folder.

Comment: Double the backtick as follows: ```$code = "\\example\example\John_Doe``'s_Folder\example.ps1"```

Comment: @NateH: The linked post doesn't apply, because it is about embedding apostrophes in _single_-quoted strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Invoke-Expression` should generally be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/); definitely [don't use it to invoke a script or external program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375).

In your case, simply use `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) to invoke your script via the path stored in variable `$code` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57678081/45375) for background information), in which case the embedded `'` needs no escaping at all:

```
$code = "\\example\example\John_Doe's_Folder\example.ps1"
& $code
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

`` "\\example\example\John_Doe`'s_Folder\example.ps1" `` turns into the following *verbatim* string content:

```
\\example\example\John_Doe's_Folder\example.ps1
```

That is, the `` ` `` was *removed* by PowerShell's parsing of the `"..."` string literal itself, inside of which `` ` `` acts as the escape character; since escape sequence `` `' `` has no special meaning, the `` ` `` is simply *removed*.

For the `` ` `` to "survive", you need to *escape the `` ` `` char. itself*, which you can do with ``` `` ```:

```
"\\example\example\John_Doe``'s_Folder\example.ps1"
```