# PowerShell Invoke-Command with FilePath on local computer - vague parameters error?

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I want to run a script in file on the local machine using Invoke-Command so I can pass in parameters with -ArgumentList.  I've been getting an error I don't understand, so I simplified my command.  When I do this:

```
Invoke-Command -FilePath 'getprocess.ps1'
```

The content of getprocess.ps1 is:

```
Get-Process
```

The error message I get is:

> Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
>
> At line:1 char:1
>
> + Invoke-Command -FilePath 'getprocess.ps1'
>
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
>
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand

I'm baffled by this error message.  What does it mean?  How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the error message doesn't make it clear, the **-FilePath** parameter makes the **-ComputerName** parameter required.  To explicitly target the local computer, use **-ComputerName localhost**.

```
Invoke-Command -FilePath 'getprocess.ps1' -ComputerName localhost
```

Comment: Your answer is technically correct (which is why I up-voted it), but it is misleading to present `-ComputerName localhost` as a _local_ invocation, for the reasons detailed in my answer. The short of it is that there's never a good reason to use `Invoke-Command` for local invocations. (In case it was you who down-voted my answer, I invite you to dispute its specific points.)

Comment: On second thought, I think that creating the misleading the impression that `-ComputerName localhost` is suitable for local invocation of scripts outweighs the technical correctness of the information about the required combination of parameters.

Answer (score 7):

**tl;dr**:

- **Generally, do not use [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) for *local* invocations** - while technically possible, there's only one specific use case where doing so is called for (see below).
- Instead, **invoke scripts *directly***:

```
.\getprocess.ps1
```

<sup>Note: Unlike `cmd.exe`, PowerShell by design requires `.\` in order to execute an executable located in the *current directory*. That is, to avoid accidental execution of executables in the current directory rather than from a directory listed in `$env:Path`, PowerShell, as a security feature, requires you to signal the intent to execute something in the current directory (`.`) explicitly.</sup>

For [*script blocks*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`), use `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) (e.g., `& { Get-Date }`).

For syntactic reasons alone, you *situationally* also need `&` for *script-file paths* if they're specified either as a *quoted* path (e.g., `& '.\getprocess.ps1'`) and/or if the path involves *variable references* (e.g.,
`& $HOME\getprocess.ps1`).

(Separately, `.` , the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) is needed in *both* cases in order to execute a script [block] *directly in the caller's scope* rather in a child scope).

---

Note that **you can technically *combine* passing a script block to `Invoke-Command` (parameter `-ScriptBlock`) with invoking a local script**:

```bash
# The script block positionally binds to the -ScriptBlock parameter.
# This is essentially the more expensive equivalent of:
#     & .\getprocess.ps1
Invoke-Command { .\getprocess.ps1 }
```

This is **slower and offers NO advantage over *direct* invocation 
(`.\getprocess.ps1` or `& .\getprocess.ps1`)**.

- For information on when `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), is *required*, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57678081/45375).
- The equivalent of using `.`, the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-), is the (also usually unnecessary) form `Invoke-Command -NoNewScope { ... }`

However, there is ***one* conceivable use case**:

If the script *isn't* an [*advanced* script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) and you wanted to take advantage of `Invoke-Command`'s stream-output-collecting
[common parameters, such as `-ErrorVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#errorvariable) (if the script or function being invoked *is* advanced, it supports these common parameters *itself*).

```bash
# Invoke locally and collect errors in $errs
Invoke-Command { .\getprocess.ps1 } -ErrorVariable errs
```

*Caveat*: At least as of PowerShell 7.2, `Invoke-Command` does *not* apply the [common `-ErrorAction` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#erroraction) to errors that occur *in the script block*, so it cannot be used to control error handling; e.g., `-ErrorAction Stop` has no effect on the commands in the script block.

---

As for **what you tried**:

Indeed, as you point out [in your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60980121/45375), **`-FilePath` *must* be combined with the

`-ComputerName` parameter** (that the error message is so generic is unfortunate).

- More generally, `-FilePath` **must be combined with *any* of the parameters that request *remote* execution**, which includes `-Session`, `-ConnectionUri`, `-VmId` / `-VmName`, and, on Unix-like platforms, `-HostName`, and `-SSHConnection`.

The **purpose of parameter `-FilePath` is to copy the *content* of a *local* script (`*.ps1` file) to a *remote* computer for execution *there***. That is, it is a convenient mechanism of executing the code of a script that is (only) available locally on a remote machine.

While **you can technically target the local computer via `-ComputerName localhost`** (or, more succinctly, via `-ComputerName .` / `-cn .`), this **does *not* amount to a *local call***:

**Whenever `-ComputerName` is specified - even with `-ComputerName localhost` -  PowerShell's *remoting infrastructure* is used**, which has **major implications**:

- The target computer - even if it is the local one - must be set up for PowerShell remoting - see [about_Remote_Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote_Requirements).
- If you target the local machine specifically, you must be running in an *elevated* session (running as administrator).
- Execution will be much slower than *direct* (local) invocation.
- Type fidelity can be lost for both input and output data, given that cross-process marshaling via PowerShell's XML-based serialization infrastructure is involved - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375).

---

That said, **if the intent is to locally *test remote execution*** of your script, and your local machine is set up as a remoting target, then use of `-ComputerName localhost` (`-ComputerName .` / `-cn .`) makes perfect sense, given that PowerShell's remoting infrastructure is then involved in the same way it would be in a truly remote call.

Note, however, that such "loopback remoting" calls require *elevation* (running as admin).

Comment: This would be a great answer for a more general "What's the recommended approach to invoke scripts on the local machine, when those scripts are in files on the local machine?"  But my question was about using Invoke-Command, which I needed for my specific case.  I didn't want to bloat my question with a paragraph of motivational background information, lest the conversation become about my motivations instead of my question.  Looks like it did anyway.

Comment: @BigScary, `Invoke-Command` is _generally the wrong tool_ to use for invocation of _local script files_. My answer focuses on that, because that is the information that matters most to future readers.
However, I've added one use case to the answer where local use of `Invoke-Command` may make sense, but it requires use of a different parameter, namely `-ScriptBlock` with a script block from which the script file is invoked.

Comment: We can also get through it without using the -ComputerName argument and instead pass an existing PSSession as argument.

Comment: Thanks, @P-L. More generally, `-FilePath` must be combined with *any* of the parameters that request _remote_ execution, which not only includes `-Session`, but also `-ConnectionUri`, `-VmId` / `-VmName`, and, on Unix-like platforms, `-HostName`, and `-SSHConnection` - I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really use `invoke-command` locally.  You use that when you're trying to run a command on a remote PC.

For example, you would want to run something like:

```bsh
invoke-Command -ComputerName REMOTE-PC -Credentials $credential -Scriptblock {Get-Process}
```

That error is basically telling you that you need to fill out more parameters that are tied to that command.

try running `Get-Help Invoke-Command` to see some info on the command and how to run it.

Comment: To be clear: It wasn't I who down-voted (on the contrary). You're right that `Invoke-Command` is primarily useful for _remote_ invocations, but you _can_ use it to invoke a command locally, namely if a _script block_ is passed to `-ScriptBlock`, whereas `-FilePath` indeed requires the use of `-ComputerName`. That said, there is _no good reason_ to use `Invoke-Command` locally.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a computername.

```
$parameters = @{
    ComputerName = '255.255.255.255'
    FilePath = 'getprocess.ps1'
    Credential = 'Domain01\User01'
}

invoke-command @parameters
```

Use your IP :) To allow that you must also include `-credential`

If that doesn't do it... `invoke-expression` may be a semi-suitable replacement for testing until you are ready to invoke-command on the remote machine.

Comment: It sounds like the OP's intent was to invoke _locally_, in which case `Invoke-Command` is the wrong tool altogether.  Suggesting use of `Invoke-Expression` is problematic, not only because it isn't necessary in this scenario, but because [it should generally be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/). That is, even in the rare cases where its use is both justified and necessary, advising against its use _in general_ is called for.

Comment: I agree with that for production scripts but for testing with trusted sources it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could run it locally like this, but you'd have to be at the administrator (elevated) prompt.  It's nice to be able to run it as a test.

```
invoke-command localhost getprocess.ps1
```

You can actually do a strange form of parallelism too:

```
invoke-command localhost,localhost,localhost getprocess.ps1
```