# Start-Process, Invoke-Command or?

Tags: powershell

Using the program got your back or GYB. I run the following command

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Gyb\gyb.exe' -ArgumentList @("--email <Email Address>", "--action backup", "--local-folder $GYBfolder", "--service-account", "--batch-size 4") -Wait
```

The issue is that when the process is done my script does not complete.

```
$GYBfolder = $GYBfolder.Replace('"', "")
$output = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Name   = $SourceGYB
    Folder = $GYBfolder
}

$filename = "C:\reports\" + $SourceGYB.Split("@")[0] + "_Backup.csv"

$output | Export-Csv $filename -NoTypeInformation | Format-Table text-align=left -AutoSize
Return $filename
```

For some reason the script stops right before the return.
I am curious to know if I should be using a different command to run GYB?
Any thoughts on why the script does not process the return?

Comment: There's probably not a reason to use `Start-Process` here. You should really only use it if you want asynchronous execution or absolutely need one of the properties it outputs or the parameters it provides.

Comment: @AdminOfThings should I change it to `invoke-command` or ?

Comment: I haven't used the command, but you should be able to just invoke it directly with the `&` (call) operator if your program path is in quotes. If you copied your arguments as is into a variable,  you'd have an array ($ArgArray for example). You could potentially run something like `& 'c:\gyb\gyb.exe' $ArgArray`.

Comment: @AdminOfThings not working and I would lose the wait.   `gyb.exe: error: unrecognized arguments: --email $SourceGYB --action backup --local-folder $GYBfolder --batch-size 4`

Comment: Don't use `Invoke-Command` locally. Use the call `&` operator instead (or omit, it's usually optional) for executing local external commands. Although you want to wait for the process to finish, so your use of `Start-Process` is appropriate here.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest I can't seem to get the program to run with & even if I ignored the wait. 
Any thoughts on why the script doesn't reach the return?

Comment: Also, what error are you getting? I'm not sure why you're trying to `Format-Table` after `Export-Csv`, there is no output from `Export-Csv`.

Comment: Your return is also extraneous in the snippet you provided

Comment: @BendertheGreatest on the next run I will look for an error variable.  No obvious errors.  I will amend the line  to `$output | Export-Csv $filename -NoTypeInformation`. I thought return would end and give me the $filename generated. Remove it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235834/discussion-between-bender-the-greatest-and-dcaz).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's great information in the comments, but let me attempt a **systematic overview**:

- To **synchronously execute external *console* applications** and capture their output, **call them *directly*** (`C:\Gyb\gyb.exe ...` or `& 'C:\Gyb\gyb.exe' ...`), do *not* use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375).

  - Only if `gyb.exe` were a ***GUI* application** would you need **`Start-Process -Wait` in order to execute it *synchronously***.

    - A simple, but non-obvious **shortcut** is to pipe the invocation to another command, such as `Out-Null`, which also forces PowerShell to wait (e.g. `gyb.exe | Out-Null`) - see below.
  - When `Start-Process` is appropriate, the most robust way to pass all arguments is as a *single* string encoding all arguments, with appropriate *embedded* `"..."` quoting, as needed; this is unfortunate, but required as a workaround for a long-standing bug: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62784608/45375).
- [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command)'s primary purpose is to invoke commands *remotely*; while it *can* be used locally, there's rarely a good reason to do so, as `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) is both more concise and more efficient - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60980641/45375).
- When you use an *array* to pass arguments to an *external application*, each element must contain just *one* argument, where parameter *names* and their *values* are considered distinct arguments; e.g., you must use `@(--'action', 'backup', ...)` rather than
  `@('--action backup', ...)`

Therefore, use the following to **run your command synchronously**:

- If `gyb.exe` is a ***console* application**:

```bash
# Note: Enclosing @(...) is optional
$argList = '--email',  $emailAddress, '--action', 'backup', '--local-folder', $GYBfolder, '--service-account', '--batch-size',  4

# Note: Stdout and stderr output will print to the current console, unless captured.
& 'C:\Gyb\gyb.exe' $argList
```

- If `gyb.exe` is a ***GUI* application**, which necessitates use of `Start-Process -Wait` (a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) is used, because it makes embedded quoting easier):

```bash
# Note: A GUI application typically has no stdout or stderr output, and
#       Start-Process never returns the application's *output*, though
#       you can ask to have a *process object* returned with -PassThru.
Start-Process -Wait 'C:\Gyb\gyb.exe' @"
--email $emailAddress --action backup --local-folder "$GYBfolder" --service-account --batch-size 4
@"
```

The **shortcut** mentioned above - piping to another command in order to force waiting for a GUI application to exit - despite being obscure, has two advantages:

- Normal argument-passing syntax can be used.
- The [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode) is set to the external program's process exit code, which does *not* happen with `Start-Process`. While GUI applications rarely report meaningful exit codes, some do, notably `msiexec`.

```bash
# Pipe to | Out-Null to force waiting (argument list shortened).
# $LASTEXITCODE will reflect gyb.exe's exit code.
# Note: In the rare event that the target GUI application explicitly
#       attaches to the caller's console and produces output there,
#       pipe to `Write-Output` instead, and possibly apply 2>&1 to 
#       the application call so as to also capture std*err* output.
& 'C:\Gyb\gyb.exe' --email $emailAddress --action backup | Out-Null
```

<sup>Note: If the above unexpectedly does *not* run synchronously, the implication is that `gyb.exe` itself launches another, asynchronous operation. There is no generic solution for that, and an application-specific one would require you to know the internals of the application and would be nontrivial.</sup>

---

A note re **argument passing with direct / `&`-based invocation**:

- Passing an array as-is to an *external program* essentially performs [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting) *implicitly*, without the need to use `@argList`<sup>[1]</sup>. That is, it passes each array element *as its own argument*.
- By contrast, if you were to pass `$argList` to a *PowerShell* command, it would be passed as a *single, array-valued* argument, so `@argList` would indeed be necessary in order to pass the elements as *separate*, *positional* arguments. However, the more typical form of splatting used with PowerShell commands is to use a [*hashtable*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables), which allows *named* arguments to be passed (parameter name-value pairs; e.g., to pass a value to a PowerShell command's
  `-LiteralPath` parameter:
  `$argHash = @{ LiteralPath = $somePath; ... }; Set-Content @argHash`

---

<sup>[1] `$args` and `@args` are largely identical in this context, but, strangely, `@argList`, honors use of `--%`, the [stop-parsing symbol operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing), even though it only makes sense in a literally specified argument list.</sup>