# Powershell script is behaving strangely (Call-Operator vs. Invoke-Expression)

Tags: powershell

one of my powershell scripts is behaving strangely. When the command is executed with the call operator (&), it works as expected. Since I am not a fan of shortcuts and the operators are not easy to read, I want to use Invoke-Expression instead. Anyway, this is not really a problem for me, but I am interested to know if this is a bug in Powershell, or if I am doing something wrong.
However, this leads to the error:
Invoke-Expression : No parameter was found that matches the parameter name "file".
In D:\Job_Monday.PS1:10 characters:34

- Invoke-Expression -Command $cmd1 -file $fil1 -wake $nas1 -close
- ```
    + CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
  ```

The script:

```
`   [String] $cmd1 = "C:\Tools\WOL2\WOL2.exe"
`   [String] $fil1 = "C:\Tools\WOL2\WOL2.profile4.xml"
`   [String] $nas1 = "SyBackup"
`   # wake-on-LAN with call operator
`   # & $cmd1 -file $fil1 -wake $nas1 -close
`   # Wake-On-LAN with Invoke expression
`   Invoke-Expression -command $cmd1 -file $fil1 -wake $nas1 -close
```

```
Many greetings from Aachen
inl1ner
```

Comment: What makes you believe `Invoke-Expression` is meant for running binaries? You might wanted to use `Start-Process` however, if your intent is to run the binary on your current session you just keep using the call operator

Comment: `Invoke-Expression` and the call operator are not the same thing. In particular, the call operator is *not* a shorthand or alias for `Invoke-Expression` (`iex` is, but that's a different matter).

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful hints. 
Start-Process with -ArgumentList is indeed the solution.

Comment: Do note that `Start-Process` is not the same thing as the call operator either, and using that instead of staying in the current session is quite different from invoking the command directly (and more cumbersome besides). It may be appropriate if your intent is to call the command and not wait for it to complete; if you combine it with waiting, however, `Start-Process` is seldom necessary, especially not for console commands.

Answer (score 3):

First, the obligatory **caveat**:

- **`Invoke-Expression`  (`iex`) should generally be *avoided*** and used only as a *last resort*, due to its inherent security risks. Superior alternatives are usually available. If there truly is no alternative, only ever use it on input you either provided yourself or fully trust - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375).

`Invoke-Expression` accepts only a *single* argument that is a *string containing arbitrary PowerShell code*, and as such it is unrelated to `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), which accepts *multiple* arguments, the first of which is a command name or path, with any remaining arguments being passed to that command.

As such, **`&` is just a syntactic variation of *direct* execution of commands**, and it is only *required* in two cases:

- If a command name (executable path) is *quoted* or contains *variable references*, it must - for syntactic reasons - be invoked with `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57678081/45375) for details.
- If the command you're invoking is given in the form of a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`).

For instance, the following statements are equivalent:

```
# Direct execution
C:\Tools\WOL2\WOL2.exe -command $cmd1 -file $fil1 -wake $nas1 -close

# Direct execution, of necessity via & in this case,
# because the executable path is *quoted*
& "C:\Tools\WOL2\WOL2.exe" -command $cmd1 -file $fil1 -wake $nas1 -close

# You can also use Invoke-Command, but that is *rarely useful*
# in *local* calls; also, inside the script block the rules re
# the & operator still apply.
Invoke-Command { & "C:\Tools\WOL2\WOL2.exe" -command $cmd1 -file $fil1 -wake $nas1 -close }
```

***Direct execution* is by far the *most typical form of invocation***, because it guarantees:

- *synchronous* execution (for *console* applications)
- in the *current console*
- with the invoked command's output streams directly connected to the current session, so that output can be captured, relayed, or redirected / suppressed.

By contrast, **[`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) is only called for in *exceptional* circumstances**:

- If you want to run in a *new* console window (by default), *asynchronously* by default (unless you pass `-Wait`)
- If you want to run a *GUI* application *synchronously*, with `-Wait` (with direct execution GUI applications launch asynchronously).
- If you need to launch a command *elevated* (as admin), with `-Verb RunAs`
- If you need to launch a command with a *as a different user*, with `-Credential`

Note that there's no direct way to capture output from a `Start-Process`-launched process - your only option is to redirect to *files*, with `-RedirectStandardOutput` and `-RedirectStandardError`.

---

Note that there's also the [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) cmdlet, which you can think of as the cmdlet equivalent to the `&` operator; however:

- It is rarely useful in *local* invocations; its primary purpose is *remote* execution of commands - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60980641/45375) for details.
- Syntactically, it requires passing a command wrapped in a script block, as shown above, and inside that script block the usual syntax rules apply, so `&` may be required *as well*.