# Invoke-command with sending scriptblock param

Tags: powershell

I have a script block

```
$test = {
param(
$path )
other stuff here...}
```

I assume I need to use `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $test` but how do I pass what the $path param should be ?

Comment: You don't need `Invoke-Command`, simply use the call operator `&` like this: `& $test argumentForPath`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.3#call-operator-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To invoke script blocks** with parameters (*locally*, in the context of the *current user*):

- do *not* use [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60980641/45375) for more information).
- **use `&`**, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-).

```bash
$test = { 
  param($path)
  "[$path]" # diagnostic output.
}

# Note: 
#  * Target parameter -path is *positionally implied*
#  * To be explicit, call: & $test -path 'my -path value' 
& $test 'my -path value'
```