# Does RegAsm need a source operator?

Tags: powershell, regasm

I have been asked to review and edit, if needed, some scripts. I have entered the relevant part of this one below. I believe its correct, but I cannot figure out if the period at the beginning of the second to last line is needed or just a typo. It appears to be a source operator, but I don't see why it'd be needed there.

As always, you folks here are the salt of the earth and deserve much more plaudits than you get and than I can give. Thank you so much for continuing to making me look better at this than I am.

```
$Assembly = 'D:\MgaLin2.dll'

."C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" -codebase -tlb $Assembly 
Copy-Item -Path D:\Mga -Destination "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\COMPANY_NAME\COMPANY_SUBFOLDER\" -Include *.*
```

Answer (score 1):

The use of a period (`.`) (the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-)) is unusual in this case, but it works.

More typically, you'll see use of `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) in this situation.

Only for *PowerShell scripts* (and script blocks, `{ ... }`) does the distinction between `.` and `&` matter (`.` then [dot-sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) the code, i.e. runs it directly in the caller's scope rather than in a child scope, as `&` does).

For *external programs*, such as `RegAsm.exe`, you can *technically* use `.` and `&` interchangeably, but to avoid conceptual confusion, it is best to stick with `&`.

Note that the reason that `&` (or `.`) is *required* in this case is that the executable path is *quoted*; the same would apply if the path contained a *variable reference* (e.g., `$env:ProgramFiles`) or a subexpression (e.g., `$($name + $ext)`).

For more information about this requirement, which is a purely *syntactic* one, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57678081/45375).