# Reference alias as variable in function

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am setting up my PowerShell profile and would like to define the alias I use for my text editor as a variable, so that if I port my profile to others, they would be free to define the alias as they wish.

Here are some of the first few lines of my profile:

```
$textEditorAlias = 'np'
$textEditorExecutable = 'notepad++.exe'

set-alias -name $textEditorAlias -value (get-command $textEditorExecutable).path -scope Global -Option AllScope

# Shortcuts to commonly used files.
function frequentFile { $textEditorAlias 'C:\<pathToFile>\fileName' }
```

My problem is the function above returns "unexpected token in expression or statement".

If I replace the function with

```
function frequentFile { np 'C:\<pathToFile>\fileName' }
```

then it works.

Is there a way to have the variable $textEditorAlias expand within the function's expression cleanly?

Thank you.

Comment: Just to highlight the root cause of your problem: Your alias definition is correct, (though can be simplified, as shown in Mathias' answer). Your only problem was the attempt to _directly_ execute a command whose name is stored in a _variable_ (`$textEditorAlias`), which in PowerShell requires `&`, the call operator, for _syntactic_ reasons - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57678081/45375) for why and when use of `&` is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aliases in PowerShell are *dead simple* - `AliasName -> CommandName` - no
arguments, no customization, just plain name-to-name mappings.

This means you don't need to call `Get-Command` explicitly - PowerShell will do that for you automatically:

```
$textEditorAlias = 'np'
$textEditorExecutable = 'notepad++.exe'
Set-Alias -Name $textEditorAlias -Value $textEditorExecutable
```

> My problem is the function above returns "unexpected token in expression or statement".

If you want to invoke a command based on a string variable, use the `&` invocation operator:

```
$textEditorAlias = 'np'
function frequentFile { & $textEditorAlias 'C:\<pathToFile>\fileName' }
```

Comment: Yup. I was testing this to be sure it worked the way I thought, and arrived at the same answer - about a minute behind you.

Comment: Awesome, thanks to both of you for your investigations :)

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I can assure you this was not the first time I've heard this specific point of confusion, I know too many bash-to-PowerShell converts ^_^

Comment: Helpful, but note that the problem was unrelated to the alias definition, which is correct (though it can be simplified, as you've shown). The sole problem was the attempt to invoke `$textEditorAlias` _without `&`_, and it is that which produced the error message. /cc @JeffZeitlin

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks, I just re-read the answer and even managed to confuse myself ^_^ Updated