# How do I run a program from powershell

Tags: powershell, command-line, syntax

I am trying to run a simple command from powershell, but as always with powershell nothing works.

I cannot get this to work regardless how many different quotes I try.

```
PS> Measure-Command { C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe test.sln /Build }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A command lines such as

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe test.sln /Build
```

wouldn't work in *any* shell, because, due to the lack of quoting around the executable path, necessitated by that **path containing *spaces***, would result in `C:\Program` being interpreted as the executable path.
In other words: ***quoting* such a path is a must**.

**What *is* PowerShell-specific is the need to use `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) whenever an executable path is quoted and/or contains variable references / expressions** (which is a purely syntactical requirement explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57678081/45375); if you don't want to think about when `&` is required, you may *always* use it).

Additionally, as you've discovered yourself, for *synchronous, console-based* operation, you must call `devenv.com`, not `devenv.exe`.<sup>[1]</sup>

Therefore:

```
Measure-Command { 
 & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.com' test.sln /Build 
}
```

Note that since the path a *literal* one (no variable references / expressions), use of *single*-quoting (`'...'`) is preferable; for more information about **string literals in PowerShell**, see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375).

---

<sup>[1] In case you need to invoke a *GUI*-subsystem application synchronously (wait for it to exit) - which run *asynchronously* by default - use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) `-Wait`.</sup>

Comment: This command "Measure-Command { & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe' test.sln /Build }" has the effect that devenv is started in the background, so Measure-Command measures how long time it takes to start it. Not how long it takes to build the solution.

Comment: Oh man. Turns out I have to use devenv.com. Then it works.

Comment: Good to know, @GenericName - I've updated the answer accordingly.