# Open notepad++ with a file in Windows PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to open a text file located on a network drive with notepad++ in Windows PowerShell.

I create the following PS1 file

```
Set-Location -Path "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\"
$Targetfile="\\server\path\myfile.txt"
.\Notepad++.exe $Targetfile
```

Error message : cannot find file

Can I run the following command in Windows PowerShell(Run exe file with path in PowerShell)

```
.\"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "\\server\path\myfile.txt"
```

Comment: "Can I run" - try it and you will see if it works. The notation ```.\abc``` means means "abc in the current location". If `Notepad++.exe` isn't in the current directory, then of course you will get a "file not found" message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:

- The answer below contains *general* information about invoking executables from PowerShell.
- Your *specific* problem may be one of the following:

  - Executable `Notepad++.exe` may be missing from directory `C:\Program Files\Notepad++`
  - The target file may not exist or the server may not be reachable.

Note that prefixing an executable path with `.\` (which refers to a file in the *current* directory) if that path is a *full* (absolute) path (as in your 2nd attempt.,
`.\"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"` ) is both logically pointless and *fails* in practice.

---

If `Notepad++.exe` is in one of the directories listed in the `$env:PATH` environment variable:

```sh
# Note: NO ".\" prefix, which is only needed to invoke an executable
#       located in the *current directory*.
Notepad++.exe $TargetFile
```

If you need to reference it by its full path, there is no need to use `Set-Location` followed by a `.\`-prefixed invocation (unless you truly need the working directory to be Notepad++'s installation directory).

To call it by its full path directly, use `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-):

```sh
& "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" $TargetFile
```

Note that `&` is *required* in this case, because your executable path is *quoted*, of necessity, due to containing embedded spaces. As the first command above shows, `&` is optional if the executable name or path is *unquoted* (and contains no variable references) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57678081/45375) for more information.