# Including a script does not work when path has special characters

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am trying to include a script inside another which is in the same folder, using the dot syntax:

```
. '.\BaseScript.ps1'
```

The path to the scripts has a folder with square brackets in the name. Even though I am using relative paths, the path error still occurs.

Moving it to some other path without special characters in the name works fine.

How can such a case be catered while using relative paths?

Comment: Cannot reproduce (tried in `PowerShell.exe` and `powershell_ise.exe` `5.1.19041.1151` as well as in `pwsh.exe` `7.1.2`) and with bizarre combinations of square brackets in paths…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, **PowerShell treats the operands to the `.` [dot-sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) and `&` [call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) operators** (which includes *implicit* invocation<sup>[1]</sup> ) **as [*wildcard expressions*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards)**, which causes **problems with paths that contain `[`**, which is a wildcard *metacharacter*.

The solution is to ***escape* the `[` as `` `[ ``**; e.g., to dot-source a script whose path is `./test[1]/script.ps1`:

```sh
# Note: '/' and '\' can be used interchangeably in PowerShell.
. ./test`[1]/script.ps1
```

**Important**: If the path is relative, it must start with `./` or `.\` (see below for full paths).

<sup>Note: `[` is a wildcard [metacharacter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacharacter), because you can use it to express character *ranges* (`[a-z]`) or *sets* (`[56]`); while `]` is clearly also needed, it is sufficient to escape `[`.</sup>

This unfortunate requirement, which also affects other contexts, is the subject of [GitHub issue #4726](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4726).

---

Alternatively - and bizarrely - as [Theo's helpful answer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68744104/45375), **the need for this escaping goes away *if you use a full path***.

```sh
# Dot-source 'script.ps1` from the same location as the running
# script ($PSScriptRoot).
# (Use $PWD to refer to the *currrent* dir.)
# Because this results in a *full* path, there is no need to escape, strangely.
. $PSScriptRoot/script.ps1
```

---

<sup>[1] `&`, which can invoke any command and runs commands written in PowerShell code in a child scope, isn't strictly needed for invocation; e.g. `& ./path/to/script.ps1` and `./path/to/script.ps1` are equivalent; however, `&` is required if the path is *quoted* and/or contains *variable references* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57678081/45375).</sup>

Comment: I didn't realize this was due to evaluation as a wildcard expression. How are the `[]` used in wildcard expressions in PowerShell? I thought we were limited to the `*` and `?` globbing characters.

Comment: I didn't know wildcard expressions in PowerShell worked with character ranges similar to `bash`. TIL, thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @BendertheGreatest. Yes, you don't see it often. Note that `Get-ChildItem`'s `-Filter` parameter does _not_ support these ranges, however, because it isn't PowerShell but the file-system APIs processing the expression.

Answer (score 6):

The way around this seems to be using a complete path to the second script:

```
. (Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath 'SecondScript.ps1')
```

Comment: `Join-Path -LiteralPath $PSScriptRoot ...`, (passing the path to `-Path` will result in wildcard globbing)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Join-Path doesn't have a `-LiteralPath` parameter.. (tested and works)

Comment: Indeed, Theo. @MathiasR.Jessen, `Join-Path` doesn't have a `-LiteralPath` parameter because it doesn't _need_ one: it is purely a string operation, no wildcard resolution is ever involved.

Answer (score 2):

@Theo has a useful workaround, but the cause is that `[]` must be escaped in paths.

```
$path = 'C:\path\`[to`]\script.ps1'
```