# string parameter value not take in powershell script when given to end of File Path

Tags: powershell, variables

I pass , string parameter to .ps script as an argument , but when the print value shows, when it passes as my file path it will not take. need some expert help to fix this.

```
    # Main-function
function main($scriptName='test') {
    #run test-suit
    run-test-suit1
    exit
}

# start run apache test plan
function run-test-suit1
{
    #start to run test plan
    New-Variable -Name 'scriptName' -Value $scriptName".bat"
    Write-host "Start Run" $scriptName "test suit";
    C:/workspace/D/Int_Module/$scriptName  -NoNewWindow -Wait

}

main @args
```

Out Put:
[image]

test.bat

```
    @ECHO OFF

echo Read and set host

set message=Load test name not Provided 
echo %message%
```

Comment: In short: An executable path that is quoted or contains variable references must - for syntactic reasons - be invoked with `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57678081/45375) to the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: Therefore: `C:/workspace/D/Int_Module/$scriptName ...` -> `& C:/workspace/D/Int_Module/$scriptName ...` (all on one line).

Comment: As an aside: There's normally no reason to use [`New-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-variable) to create variables - `$scriptName = "$scriptName.bat"` will do.

Comment: @mklement0 it worked with &

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to invoke cmd from powershell:

```
# start run apache test plan
function run-test-suit1()
{
    #start to run test plan
    New-Variable -Name 'scriptName' -Value $scriptName".bat"
    Write-host "Start Run" $scriptName "test suit";

    cmd.exe /c C:/workspace/D/Int_Module/$scriptName -NoNewWindow -Wait 
}
```

Comment: Calling via `cmd.exe /c` is a viable workaround, but the proper solution is to use `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-)