# Can i run a exe with cmd or powershell if i have spaces in username?

Tags: powershell, cmd, syntax, arguments

Ex:

```
cmd /C start C:\Users\Bob Builder\Desktop\New Folder\test.exe
```

I'm trying to use cmd to start a file but since there are spaces in the path, cmd is throwing an error after Bob.

Error:

> "Windows cannot find C:\Users\Bob. Make sure you typed the name
> correctly, then try again."
>
> The system cannot find the file C:\Users\Bob.

Its simply failing to accept the spaces. It's driving me crazy because I'm spoiled with C# working out of the box. I don't know much about this, I have been spending way too much time trying to figure this out. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how is python, C# and C++ related here? Don't do tag spam

Comment: It's being read as separate tokens. Use quotes. You also don't have to call on cmd.exe. just run it from PowerShell.

Comment: Where are you executing the command? From a `cmd` prompt? From a `powershell` prompt? Somewhere else? You just edited in the [tag:powershell] tag even though there's no indication in the question.

Comment: What is your definition of "working out of the box"?  c# requires quotes around strings/paths.  PowerShell is even more forgiving when it come to which type of quotes you use.

Comment: My definition is string apppath = @"mydamnnormalpathherewithnobullshit"

Comment: For some reason I'm starting to think that its your "test.exe" app that might be where the actual problem is at.  Does it load okay if you run it directly?  Is it console or GUI?

Comment: its a console app that is basically automating some file management for me. It's not the problem because if there is no spaces in it, if i throw my test.exe in programdata directory it runs just fine. Its the spaces in the directory.

Answer (score 3):

- In order for a **path that contains *spaces*** to be recognized as a *single* path (argument), it **must be *quoted***.
- In order for an executable to **execute in the *current console window***, synchronously, with its streams connected to the calling shell, it **must be invoked *directly*, not via `start`**.

Direct invocation from `cmd.exe` (only `"..."` quoting supported):

```
"C:\Users\Bob Builder\Desktop\New Folder\test.exe"
```

From PowerShell:

```
& 'C:\Users\Bob Builder\Desktop\New Folder\test.exe'
```

Note:

- PowerShell also supports `'...'` strings (single-quoted), which are *verbatim* strings that are preferable to `"..."` (double-quoted) ones if you do not require expansion of variables (string interpolation) - see the conceptual [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules) help topic.
- For syntactic reasons, PowerShell requires the use of `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) to invoke commands that are *quoted* and/or *contain variable references* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57678081/45375) for details.

---

By contrast, **use `start` in `cmd.exe` / [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) in PowerShell** (whose built-in alias is also `start`) to **launch an executable in a *new window*** (on Windows), *asynchronously*, with no (direct) ability to capture the launched executable's output:

From `cmd.exe`:

```
start "title" "C:\Users\Bob Builder\Desktop\New Folder\test.exe"
```

Note:

- Specifying `"title"` - i.e. a self-chosen (console) *window title* - is *required for syntactic reasons* in this case: without it, the double-quoted path itself would be interpreted as the window title, and the - implied - executable to launch would be another `cmd.exe` instance.
- Note that if you launch a *GUI* application this way, the title argument is irrelevant, because no new *console* window is created.
  Conversely, if you launch a *console* application specified by double-quoted path and therefore *must* use a title argument, note that `""` will result in the new window having *no* title.

From PowerShell (parameter `-FilePath` is positionally implied):

```
Start-Process 'C:\Users\Bob Builder\Desktop\New Folder\test.exe'
```

Note:

- `Start-Process` does *not* support specifying a window title, so you may want to call `cmd.exe`'s internal `start` command for that (or other features not supported by `Start-Process`, such as specifying the process priority).
- To work around quoting problems, invoke `cmd.exe`'s `start` from PowerShell by passing the entire `start` command *as a single string* to `cmd /c`:

  ```
  cmd /c 'start "title" "C:\Users\Bob Builder\Desktop\New Folder\test.exe"'
  ```

Answer (score 1):

`cmd /C start "C:\Users\Bob Builder\Desktop\New Folder\test.exe"`

Quotes are your friend. Sometimes even double quotes are too!

Comment: That is loading up the program inside a cmd window the file is not opening but a cmd with its icon opened. How do i get the exe to execute normally?

Comment: Try it without start - `cmd /C "C:\Users\Bob Builder\Desktop\New Folder\test.exe"`

Comment: While the need for quotes is a good pointer, your `start` command is broken - the double-quoted path is interpreted as a _window title_, and the program that is launched is `cmd.exe` by default. I know you just built on the OP's own attempt, but it's also worth pointing out that you need the `cmd /c` neither from `cmd.exe` nor from PowerShell. Though in PowerShell, where `start` is an alias for `Start-Process`, `start "C:\Users\Bob Builder\Desktop\New Folder\test.exe"` would work as-is.  All of this assumes that the intent is to launch in a _new window_, _asynchronously_.

Answer (score -2):

Seems like cmd won't work for me. Powershell worked with this script:

```
$env:Path += ";C:\Users\Bob Builder\Desktop\New Folder\"
test.exe
```

Comment: From `cmd.exe`, use `"C:\Users\Bob Builder\Desktop\New Folder\test.exe"`. While your PowerShell workaround is effective, you don't need a workaround; use `& 'C:\Users\Bob Builder\Desktop\New Folder\test.exe'`