# How to execute C:\...\executable commands in terminal?

Tags: bash, powershell, shell

`Question`

I'm trying to execute a command with the format `{C:\...\executable} build {C:\...\executable} link`. Here is the specific example I'm trying to execute. All it does is install a `golang` module which lets me debug in vs code.

`C:\Program Files\Go\bin\go.exe build -o C:\Users\linds\go\bin\dlv-dap.exe github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv`

The issue i'm having is that I don't know how to actually execute it. I've tried running it in `powershell` and `bash` but both come back and say that I cant run program with the form `C:\...`.

**How do I execute code with the following or similar formats?**

~~

Sorry that my descriptions of the issue aren't the best because frankly I hardly know what I'm dealing with right here. I can clarify more if needed.

Comment: You have a space after `Program`. In Powershell, this would run a program named C:Program with `Files\Go\bin\go.exe` as first argument. In bash, the whole line would be nonsense anyway, due to the backslashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're trying to **invoke an executable whose path contains *spaces*, you must *quote* the path** in order for a shell to recognize it as a single argument.

- From **PowerShell**:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\Go\bin\go.exe' build -o C:\Users\linds\go\bin\dlv-dap.exe github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv
```

<sup>Note: `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), isn't *always* needed, but *is* needed whenever a command path is quoted and/or contains variable references - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57678081/45375) for details.</sup>

- From **`cmd.exe`**:

```
"C:\Program Files\Go\bin\go.exe" build -o C:\Users\linds\go\bin\dlv-dap.exe github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv
```