# Escape the period character in a command flag within a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell

I have a command similar to the following that I need to run as part of a PowerShell script:

```
gfpca -run.config default.conf
```

However, I receive the error `Command not found: .conf` on the output. This happens if I run with `Invoke-Expression` as well. I have also tried escaping the character, but don't see a difference:

```
Invoke-Expression('gfpca -run`.config default.conf')
```

How can I run this command within PowerShell?

Comment: Try `& gfpca '-run.config' 'default.conf'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `&` invocation operator to invoke the program and use regular `'` single-quotes to qualify the argument boundaries:

```
& gfpca '-run.config' 'default.conf'
```

Now, PowerShell will pass `-run.config` and `default.conf` to `gfpca` as-is without attempting to interpret them as native parameters

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**

Due to an **[unfortunate *bug*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6291)**, still present as of this writing (PowerShell 7.3.4), an argument passed to an *external program* that starts with `-` and contains `.` requires *escaping* or quoting, which in the simplest case means:

```bash
# Note the ` before -
gfpca `-run.config default.conf
```

To be clear: **This shouldn't be necessary**.

---

[Mathias R. Jessen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71395323/45375) provides an effective solution, but let me add some context:

- You only need to escape or quote *one* of your arguments, `-run.config`, due to a **PowerShell *bug*, where passing an unquoted argument that starts with `-` and contains a `.` to an *external program*  is mistakenly passed as *two* arguments**.

  - In other words: Without escaping or quoting such an argument (see below), PowerShell mistakenly passes `-run.config` as separate arguments `-run` and `.config`
  - The bug, still present as of this writing (PowerShell 7.3.4), has been reported in [GitHub issue #6291](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6291), where it was acknowledged as such, but is awaiting a fix; it is one of several bugs relating to `-`-prefixed tokens.
- While using `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), *unconditionally* for command invocations is a robust approach, it is important to note that it is only necessary *if the command name or path is quoted and/or contains variable references* - which isn't the case here.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57678081/45375) for details.
- `Invoke-Expression` (`iex`) should *generally* be avoided - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375). Specifically, do not use it to invoke an external program or PowerShell script - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375).

  - As an aside: Your call, `InvokeExpression('...')`, uses *pseudo method syntax*, which is to be avoided: PowerShell functions, cmdlets, scripts, and external programs must be invoked *like shell commands* - `Invoke-Expression '...'` - *not* like C# methods. That is, don't put (`(...)` around the argument list, and separate argument with *whitespace*, not with `,`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65208621/45375) for more information.

---

While `` ` `` (PowerShell's escape character), which you tried to use, *is* (a) key to the solution, it *must be applied to the initial `-`*, which prevents PowerShell from (inappropriately) parsing the argument according to the rules of PowerShell-native parameter names.<sup>[1]</sup>

```bash
# Note the ` before - 
gfpca `-run.config default.conf
```

As shown in Mathias' answer, using a *quoted string* around  the whole argument (e.g. `'-run.config'`) is an alternative.

---

<sup>[1] Because parameter names aren't expected to require escaping, what follows `-` is parsed *verbatim*, up to the first `.`. Therefore, your attempt to `` ` ``-escape the `.` character was ineffective: `` ` `` wasn't recognized as an escape character and therefore retained, and the bug still kicked in. By contrast, `` ` ``-escaping the initial `-` prevents PowerShell from parsing the entire token *as a parameter*, which bypasses the bug</sup>