# NVIM: executing external command does not execute command - but also throws no error

Tags: windows, powershell, neovim

I am trying to get Nvim to execute the ls command by typing :!ls, this is the output:
[image: output picture - the german text is irrelevant]
(interestingly after typing :!ls and pressing enter, the ls gets put in quotes)

my init.vim file looks like this:
[image: init.vim picture]

The interesting thing is, if I change the shell-setting to cmd, the output of :!ls now looks like this (which is exactly what a new cmd shell looks like):
[image: output picture with cmd shell]

So it looks like, using the external command, nvim starts a shell but does not execute the ls command. I should also mention that before I created the init.vim file, the external command was working - however - it was using cmd instead of powershell, which I do not want and which is why I created the init.nvim file.

PS: at first I've also tried setting shell=powershell, which didn't work either

PPS: in vim :!ls works as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(To get `cmd.exe` to work, you'd need to set `shellcmdflag` to `/c`, otherwise any command passed is ignored, as you've experienced.)

The **culprit turned out to be `\"` as the `shellquote` setting**, as a result of which **what you typed was accidentally getting enclosed in `\"...\"`** when passed to the PowerShell's [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)'s `-Command` parameter, causing PowerShell - after its command-line parsing - to execute `"ls"`, *including* the quotes; the next section explains how PowerShell interprets such a command.

The **correct setting** is:

```
set shellquote="
```

---

Your first screenshot implies what PowerShell ended up executing was `"ls"`, *including* the double quotes, which predictably results in verbatim `ls` getting printed:

**To PowerShell, `"ls"` is a double-quoted *string literal*, whose value is simply *echoed*** when submitted as a command, due to PowerShell's implicit output behavior (see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665963/45375) for background information).

That is, `"ls"` is equivalent to `echo "ls"`, to put it in terms of a traditional shell (`echo` in PowerShell is an alias of the [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) cmdlet).

To submit `ls` (an alias of [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)) as a *command*:

- **Do *not* use quoting**, given that it isn't needed here (the command name, `ls`, contains neither spaces nor other PowerShell metacharacters):

  ```
  :!ls
  ```
- **Alternatively, use `&`**, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-):

  ```
  :!& "ls"
  ```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57678081/45375) for why use of `&` is needed with quoted commands.