# how to run a specific cmd command in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, cmd, syntax

I have the following command that I can run in `cmd.exe`:

```bash
"C:\Program Files (x86)\FireEye\xagt\xagt.exe" -g "C:\tmp\xagt_%computername%_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt"
```

I just need to run the above mentioned command in PowerShell.

I tried to use the symbol `&` before the command, but I got an error. I also tried to use the following commands:

```
###########################
$cmd = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\FireEye\xagt\xagt.exe'
$arg1 = '-g C:\tmp\xagt_%computername%_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt'
& $cmd $arg1
########################################

Start-Process -FilePath "xagt.exe" -WorkingDirectory "C:\Program Files (x86)\FireEye\xagt" -ArgumentList "-g "C:\tmp\xagt_%computername%_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt""
############################################

PS C:\Program Files (x86)\FireEye\xagt> & 'xagt.exe -g "C:\tmp\xagt_%computername%_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,
_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt"'
& : The term 'xagt.exe -g
"C:\tmp\xagt_%computername%_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt"' is not
recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:3
+ & 'xagt.exe -g "C:\tmp\xagt_%computername%_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%% ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (xagt.exe -g "C:...time:~6,2%.txt":String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Program Files (x86)\FireEye\xagt> Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
>>        xagt.exe -g "C:\tmp\xagt_%computername%_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6
%.txt"
>> }
xagt.exe : The term 'xagt.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:2 char:8
+        xagt.exe -g "C:\tmp\xagt_%computername%_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10 ...
+        ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (xagt.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

All trials were not successful , there is something in thd syntax that I cannot understand.

Comment: "I tried to use the symbol & before the command but I got error" - please show us _that_ error :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a legacy command line way to create a date stamp on your file:

```
%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
```

Use the powershell command instead:

```
(Get-Date).ToString('yyyymmdd_HHmmss')
```

This is a legacy command line way to get computername:

```
%computername%
```

Use the powershell command instead:

```
$env:COMPUTERNAME
```

Try declaring your path and Outputfile path in powershell first then just call the exe with these set variables:

```
$WorkingDir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\FireEye\xagt"
$OutputFile = "C:\Temp\xagt_" +[string]$env:COMPUTERNAME + "_" + [string]((Get-Date).ToString('yyyymmdd_HHmmss')) + ".txt"

cd $WorkingDir
.\xagt.exe -g $OutputFile
```

- There are many ways to start an exe in powershell, the method described is the most simple and should meet your needs.

Comment: Some good pointers, but I wouldn't recommend using `cd` (`Set-Location`) in a PowerShell script, as the current location invariably changes _for the whole session_.
Also, environment variables are always strings, and `.ToString()` obviously also returns a string, so your `[string]` casts are unnecessary.
A more PowerShell-idiomatic solution would be to use string interpolation: `"C:\Temp\xagt_${env:COMPUTERNAME}_$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyymmdd_HHmmss')).txt"`

Comment: @mklement0 Eh, not saying you are wrong by any means but I don't think a new coder needs this level of detail. I removed the word "DOS" since it's apparently triggering. The other comment is a matter of taste.. I do prefer your line but I was trying to keep it simple I suppose at the time I wrote mine.

Comment: If by "triggering" you mean "triggering valid criticism of technically incorrect and potentially confusing terminology", I agree. Replacing "DOS" with "legacy" is an improvement, but an inadequate one.
Yes, you could consider the choice between string concatenation with `+` and expandable strings (string interpolation) a matter of taste.
By contrast, use of redundant `[string]` casts and unqualified use of `cd` are not, to the detriment of readers who aren't PowerShell experts.

Answer (score 0):

I run the command using the following syntax

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\FireEye\xagt\"
cmd /c xagt.exe -g "C:\tmp\xagt_%computername%_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

Delegate the entire call to `cmd.exe`, passing it as a *single string* (`'...'`) to `cmd /c`:

```
cmd /c ' "C:\Program Files (x86)\FireEye\xagt\xagt.exe" -g "C:\tmp\xagt_%computername%_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt" '
```

---

##### Background information:

- You're using `cmd.exe`-format environment-variable expansions (e.g., `%computername%`, `%date:~-4,4%`), which PowerShell doesn't support, so you indeed *must* call via `cmd.exe`

  - The alternative is to use equivalent PowerShell constructs, as shown in [Mike Q's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75816272/45375).
- If the need to call via `cmd.exe` *weren't* in the picture:

  - You would indeed need `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) in order to invoke your executable, given that its path is (of necessity) *quoted* (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57678081/45375) for why this is needed).
  - Nothing else would need to change; that is, *arguments* to pass to your executable still need to be passed *individually* - you cannot pass them *as a single string*.

    ```
    # To illustrate the syntax, using a simplified -g argument.
    & "C:\Program Files (x86)\FireEye\xagt\xagt.exe" -g "C:\tmp\foo.txt"

    # !! BROKEN - do NOT use a *single string* for the arguments.
    # If you wanted to provide the arguments via a variable, use an *array*
    #    $passThruArgs = @('-g', 'C:\tmp\foo.txt')
    $passThruArgs = '-g "C:\tmp\foo.txt"'
    & "C:\Program Files (x86)\FireEye\xagt\xagt.exe" $passThruArgs
    ```
- While [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75815223/45375) works, it uses `cd` (a built-in alias of the [`Set-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location) cmdlet), but there is no need for it, especially given that `Set-Location` is best avoided *in scripts*, given that in PowerShell changing the location invariably affects the *whole session*.

  - If you do need to change the current location (working directory), use the following idiom to ensure that the previous location is restored on exiting the script:

    ```
    try {

      # Switch to the desired location, saving the current one.
      # In this example, the script's own dir. is switched to.
      Push-Location $PSScriptRoot

      # ... work in the new location.

      # Sample commands: Show the now current location and wait for
      # the user to press Enter. If you abort the script with Ctrl-C
      # at that point, the `finally` clause still executes and restores the
      # original location.
      $pwd | Out-Host
      pause

    } finally {
      # Restore the previous location,
      # even if the script was aborted.
      Pop-Location
    }
    ```