# How do I start the conda environment in a ps1 script instead of starting conda when powershell starts?

Tags: powershell, anaconda, conda

I want to start a script for powershell7. powershell itself does not configure the conda environment. It needs to start the conda environment in this way:

```
pwsh.exe -NoLogo -NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command  
"& 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\shell\\condabin\\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3' "}
```

I now have a requirement to start the conda environment on an existing script, which I know can be done with `source` command on linux, but cannot be done with powershell with the Invoke-Excution command.

Here is a sample code that I want to use to start the conda environment:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass

$startCondaScript = " 'C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate 'C:\ProgramData\anaconda3' "
$workingDirectory = "D:\conda\condaProject"
$virtualEnvName = "Project"

Invoke-Expression $startCondaScript

Set-Location $workingDirectory

conda activate $virtualEnvName

python gui.py
```

It runs with error.

```
conda: The term 'conda' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
conda: C:\Users\QU\Desktop\StarRailCopilot.ps1:12:1
Line |
  12 |  conda activate $virtualEnvName
     |  ~~~~~
     | The term 'conda' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, 
     | or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Just as I was about to finish my question, my chatgpt came to my aid and solved the problem.

I didn't see any questions about this on StackOverFlow, so I'm going to post it anyway to gather better, more polished answers.

Comment: As an aside: In PowerShell, ``\`` never needs escaping as ``\\``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know why the command works [when I] just added an `&`

Because your script path is *quoted*, in order for PowerShell to recognize it *as a command to execute* rather than as a *string literal whose value to output*, use of `&` is a syntactic necessity; it also necessary for commands stored in *variables* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57678081/45375) for details.

> `Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force`

There is usually no point in calling [`Set-ExecutionPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy) *from inside a script*, given that the fact that your script executes to begin with by definition implies that script execution *is already enabled*.

- The only reason to call it would be to (temporarily) enact a *more permissive* policy than the one in effect (`Bypass` unconditionally enables script execution, whether signed or not, whether downloaded from the web or not.)
- If you want to enable script execution *persistently* for your user account - assuming that execution policies aren't controlled via GPOs on your machine -  run the following *once* (which will take effect in subsequent sessions):

  ```
  Set-ExecutionPolicy -Force -Scope CurrentUser RemoteSigned
  ```

  - The `RemoteSigned` policy strikes a balance between convenience and security.
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71564847/45375) for more information.

There is no need to use [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression), which is [generally to be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375) - just invoke the commands directly.

Therefore:

```
$condaScript = "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1"
$workingDirectory = "D:\conda\condaProject"
$virtualEnvName = "Project"

& $condaScript
conda activate $virtualEnvName

Set-Location -LiteralPath $workingDirectory
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I post the code that will work:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force

$condaScript = "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1"
$workingDirectory = "D:\conda\condaProject"
$virtualEnvName = "Project"

Invoke-Expression "& '$condaScript' ; conda activate '$virtualEnvName'"

Set-Location $workingDirectory
```

I don't know why the command works just added an '&', When I remove the &, the command will say that conda is not found.

Comment: & is equivalent to invoke-command, it basically executes the script file in current context rather than echoing a string