# Running an EXE file using PowerShell from a directory with spaces in it

Tags: powershell, spaces

I'm trying to run MSTest.exe from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE`. What's more, I'm taking all of the assemblies in my current directory and setting them as separate /testcontainer arguments. I cannot figure out how to do this without PowerShell complaining.

```
$CurrentDirectory = [IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory()

$MSTestCall = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe"'

foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $CurrentDirectory) 
{
    if($file.name -match "\S+test\S?.dll$" )
    {
        $MSTestArguments += "/TestContainer:" + $file + " "
    }
}

$MSTestArguments += " /resultsFile:out.trx"
$MSTestArguments += " /testsettings:C:\someDirectory\local64.testsettings"

Invoke-Expression "$MSTestCall $MSTestArguments"
```

The error I get from this code is:

> Invoke-Expression : You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '/' operator.

I don't get this error when I try to call a mstest.exe in a directory without a space in the name (no additional "'s are needed).

When I try using `&`,

```
&$MSTestCall $MSTestArguments
```

It hands $MSTestArguments over as a single argument, which MSTest prompty throws out. Suggestions?

Comment: The extra quotes here are unnecessary (and in fact cause problems in this case) - `$MSTestCall = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe"'`. Once you put `"foo bar.exe"` into a variable `$foo` then it contains that string complete with the space. Calling `& $foo` works as expected i.e it executes the command named by the string in variable `$foo`.

Comment: One other note about strings and regexes.  Generally, unless I need to specify a PowerShell variable within the regex I use single quoted strings so PowerShell doesn't "interpret" things like $1.  Also you specify `.dll` and I suspect you want `\.dll`.  The whole thing with single quotes - `'\S+test\S?\.dll$'`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would recommend you to use an *array* of parameters and the operator `&`. See the examples in my answer in here: [Executing a Command stored in a Variable from Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592851/executing-a-command-stored-in-a-variable-from-powershell/3593445#3593445)

In this case the code should be something like this:

```
$MSTestCall = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe"
$MSTestArguments = @('/resultsFile:out.trx', '/testsettings:C:\someDirectory\local64.testsettings')

foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $CurrentDirectory)  
{ 
    if($file.name -match "\S+test\S?.dll$" ) 
    { 
        $MSTestArguments += "/TestContainer:" + $file
    } 
} 

& $MSTestCall $MSTestArguments
```

Comment: Excellent. This is a great solution. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Does this work?

```
$MSTestCall = @'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe"'@
```

Comment: That won't work because you have to start a newline after the opening here string sequence `@'`.