# Calling MSTest with Powershell

Tags: powershell, mstest

I am trying to execute from powershell the Visual Studio's tool MSTest with no success:

```
$testDLL = "myTest.dll"
$mstestPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe"    
$arguments = " /testcontainer:" + $testDLL + " /test:UnitTest1"

Invoke-Expression "$mstestPath $arguments"
```

I get this error:  "The term 'x86' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,..."
Any idea? Thanks.

**Edit:**

Ok, the problem was solved using "&" instead "Invoke-Expression" and creating separated variables for each argument, it doesn't work for me just using both in one var:

```
$testDLL = "myTest.dll"
$mstestPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe"    
$argument1 = "/testcontainer:" + $testDLL
$argument2 = "/test:UnitTest1"

& $mstestPath $argument1
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868342/running-an-exe-using-powershell-from-a-directory-with-spaces-in-it

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)" has a space so add quotes to your string `$mstestPath = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\...\IDE\mstest.exe"'`

Answer (score 9):

I'd recommend using the `&` operator in the case (see comment David Brabant).

However, if you must use Invoke-Expression you could convert `$mstestPath` to its shortpath equivalent.

```
$testDLL = "myTest.dll"
$fs = New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject
$f = $fs.GetFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe")
$mstestPath = $f.shortpath   
$arguments = " /testcontainer:" + $testDLL + " /test:UnitTest1"
Invoke-Expression "$mstestPath $arguments"
```

Comment: nice answer. Do you have any idea how to parse the results?

Comment: You export the results out to a trx file using the resultsfile switch: `/resultsfile:c:\temp\tests.trx` then you can parse the trx file: http://dbarrowstechblog.blogspot.com.au/2012/08/parsing-mstest-results-trx-files.html?_sm_au_=iNVjjVLrnLPWRJ0j'' or http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e06010/read-trx-file-from-C-Sharp/